# Open GL ES 2.0 with Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was wondering if someone could recommended a book that covers both android game developement and OpenGL ES 2.0. I have found some books with OpenGL 1.0, but I have heard that the syntax for OpenGL es 2.0 is totally different.

Comment: There have been numerous other questions related to this one here. I suggest you search them out and read through them, they will probably be useful.

Comment: This question is off topic for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any book for OpenGL ES 2.0, everything is in the web ;)

I started with [All about OpenGL ES 2.x](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/02/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-23/), and I looked into sources of samples in Android NDK. You can also look into [Maemo examples](http://wiki.maemo.org/SimpleGL_example). Khronos offers an [OpenGL ES 2.0 quick syntax reference](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengl-quick-reference-card.pdf).

Comment: Thank you I wanted to get a book because I was unable to find any tutorials online.

Comment: You can also download Adreno SDK, there are a lot of examples too ;)

Comment: Look more thoroughly -- there are quite a few.

Answer (score 2):

I remember [Beginning Android Games](http://www.amazon.es/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430230428/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337449283&sr=8-1) and [Pro Android Games](http://www.amazon.es/Pro-Android-Games-Books-Professionals/dp/1430226471/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1337449228&sr=8-1) as books with good explanations on Game programming on Android and OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you, but I find this book very good [OpenGL® ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321502795). The books explains how OpenGL ES 2.0 works and gives a lot of code examples in C language. If you know basics of it, then you should have no big problems of translating them to Java code.